# Vue.js consume json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

My problem is with this json.
http://dev-rexolution.pantheonsite.io/api/noticias

I need to consume with vuejs 2 only the first element of the array to be able to display it, working with the console I worked but with no vuejs.

This console log work:       console.log(response.data[0].title[0].value);

```
<template>
  <div class="Box Box--destacado1">
    <div class="Media Media--rev">
      <div class="Media-image">
          </div>
              <div class="Media-body">
                <span class="Box-info">{{ noticias[0].field_fecha[0].value}}</span>
                <h3 class="Box-title">
                 <a href="">{{ /*noticias[0].title[0].value */}}</a>
                </h3>
               <p class="Box-text">{{/*noticias[0].field_resumen[0].value*/}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    noticias: [],
    errors: []
  }),

  // Fetches posts when the component is created.
  created() {
    axios.get(`http://dev-rexolution.pantheonsite.io/api/noticias`)
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.noticias = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"not working"*? Also, why use a string template literal for your URL?

Comment: A quick look in your browser's *Console* and *Network* dev tools should show up any problems you might be running into

Comment: This template is generate by Drupal 8 module Rest. Not work because it returns objects as undefined

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer than that; *"returns objects as undefined"* where? Which piece of code causes the error? Provided you're web app is running on `http://localhost:8080`, this should work for you

Comment: This piece of code not work in access to json elements. {{ noticias[0].field_fecha[0].value}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into an issue where your template is attempting to show data that doesn't exist until the AJAX request has completed.

I would set a flag to indicate when the data is available and toggle the display using `v-if`. For example

Template

```
<div class="Media-body" v-if="loaded">
```

Script

```
data () {
  loaded: false,
  noticias: [],
  errors: []
}
```

and in your `created` hook

```
.then(response => {
  this.loaded = true
  this.noticias = response.data
})
```

---

Alternatively, set up your initial `noticias` array with some dummy data

```
noticias: [{
  title: [{ value: null }]
  field_fecha: [{ value: null }]
  field_resumen: [{ value: null }]
}]
```

Comment: Sorry @Fabián, I don't understand your question

Comment: @Fabián the problem was, your template was attempting to access data in a very specific structure. When `noticias` was just an empty array, you were getting errors. If you make it at least structurally like what your template expects, it won't have errors

Comment: Woow, Thanks @Phil